# Android SQLite escape characters not working

Tags: android, sqlite, escaping

I've searched a lot around S.O. but never found an answer, so I post a question here:

I'm developing an Android App (Italian Language) and when I call an SQL Insert Function the App crashes because of an apostrophe character inside the text, like this:

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Famiglia (Description) VALUES ('Quando il sole s'allontana la vita diviene più sana')");
```

I tried to escape the word `s'allontana` so that it becomes `s\'allontana` but this isn't working.

Really dunno what to do...

Comment: Try doubling up the single quotes.

Comment: Use Prepared Statements. That is the only real solution here

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes are escaped by typing them twice. Like:

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Famiglia (Description) VALUES ('Quando il sole s''allontana la vita diviene più sana')");
```